# PHP DOMDocument 要素の変更

Tags: php, html, dom

親の要素名`old`を`new`に変更したいです。
`old`の子要素は何階層も複数あるものとします。

```html
<old><span>test1</span><span>test2<span>test3</span></span></old>
```

↓

```html
<new><span>test1</span><span>test2<span>test3</span></span></new>
```

調べたところ単純に置き換えはできないようなので、
`new`を作成し、`old`の中身をコピーする方法を探しています。
下記の方法では`old`ごと入ってしまうので中身だけ全てコピーする方法はないでしょうか？

```php
$orgdoc = new DOMDocument;
$orgdoc->loadXML("<old><span>test1</span><span>test2<span>test3</span></span></old>");
$node = $orgdoc->getElementsByTagName("old")->item(0);

$newdoc = new DOMDocument;
$newdoc->loadXML("<new></new>");

$node = $newdoc->importNode($node, true);
$newdoc->documentElement->appendChild($node);

echo $newdoc->saveHTML();
```

↓

```html
<new><old><span>test1</span><span>test2<span>test3</span></span></old></new>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

子ノードをコピーします。具体的には、

```php
$node = $newdoc->importNode($node, true);
$newdoc->documentElement->appendChild($node);
```

を以下の様に変更します。

```php
foreach($node->childNodes as $el){
  $el = $newdoc->importNode($el, true);
  $newdoc->documentElement->appendChild($el);
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。繰り返し処理する必要があるのですね。解決しました。